# onFormSubmit(e) returning NULL e value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I am trying to work with data submitted by users via Google Forms.  My trigger is tied to the spreadsheet on Form Submit, but when I use the following code, I get "e" returned with a NULL value and I can't do anything with it.  I am submitting it through the forms and not just running a script.  My spreadsheet is updating fine, but I can do anything with the values I'm getting.

```
    function getTickets(e) {
      var values = e.namedValues;
      Logger.log(e);
      Logger.log(values);
    }
```

The exact error I get is:

> [20-03-10 21:48:22:765 EDT] TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
> at getTickets(Tickets:2:18)

Comment: Please clearly state your question instead of a statement in the subject.

Comment: If your on the new V8  try switching back

Comment: Thank you, @Cooper! Switching back to the old version worked perfectly!

Comment: Could you please post the change made that did work as an answer to this question so that everyone accessing this question can clearly see the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was reported that user was getting a nulll for event object parameter values.  I suggested trying to switch back to legacy ES5 because it’s easy to do and it seems to fix many difficult to understand problems.